# how XEN chontrol cores and whether there is a API in Linux to run process on designated core

Tags: linux, cloud, instance, xen, cpu-cores

how XEN chontrol cores and whether there is a API in Linux to run process on designated core

Comment: Are you asking from the OpenStack admin or an API user? That is to say, is your question: "I have an OpenStack installed and would like to know how to assign a CPU core to instances" or as a user: "Is it possible to assign a CPU core to an instance via API?"

Comment: On a side note, if this is as an admin I highly suggest checking out  https://ask.openstack.org/.

Comment: What flavors and images have you created so far?

Comment: maybe my question should be "Is it possible to assign a CPU core to an instance via API?"
I am not a amin or user.I just  want to know what technologies used in openstack  to assign a CPU core to an instance.@rdodev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is done using libvirt driver. You can specify the cpuset in nova configuration file and when the instance is being spawned, the libvirt driver checks the config file and the specified value is put in the instance's xml. The only shortcoming is that the given cpuset works for all the instances being spawned on that host. There is no way to specify different cpu cores for different instances. And yeah, there is no API to do this. Admin has to specify it explicitly in the config file. HTH.

Comment: These days I know that CPU cores are controled by XEN(or similar system) and nova just use api powered by 
these system.
I want to know how XEN chontrol cores and whether there is a API in Linux to process run on designated core.

Thank you all the same.